# Pattern dfferences between NFA/DFA regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the following regex to extract numeric value from JSON:

```
"version":\s*(\d+)(\.\d)?
```

Which works when using java.util.Pattern library which uses NFA.

Now I'm trying to use the same pattern using another library ([This one](https://github.com/fulmicoton/multiregexp) which is a wrapper to another library that uses DFA (`https://www.brics.dk/automaton/faq.html`).

My question - Why the same regex pattern doesn't find anything with DFA (second library)? Do I need to change something in the pattern to fit for DFA regex?

Comment: Are you sure it's actually an issue with NFA vs DFA and not something in the library itself? Skimming the GitHub page it does say "*The library does not handle groups.*", so it seems to me that your regex is simply not compatible with that library.

Comment: Capturing groups are probably fine to use. It seems the library does not support many regular regex features, but reminds me of Lucene engine. Try `"version": *([0-9]+)([.][0-9])?`. If it does not match, check if the regex matches the whole string, if it does not, probably that will be the reason and you will need to try `.*"version": *([0-9]+)([.][0-9])?.*` or even `(.|\n)*"version": *([0-9]+)([.][0-9])?(.|\n)*` - but it will be a very bad regex already. `(.|\n)` is the only pattern that matches all kinds of chars in Lucene engine.

Comment: Did my comment help?